# Adding a componentDidMount event listener to a PureScript Thermite component

Tags: reactjs, purescript

My goal is to call a remote api in order to populate a Purescript Thermite component at startup, for this I need (I think) the *componentDidMount* event handler which is not directly available on Thermite but is exposed by the lower level react bindings *Purescript-React*

So I try to use the *createReactSpec* function to add the *componentDidMount* event listener but I get a type mismatch involving a *rigid type variable* that I don't understand (I'm quite new to purescript / haskell).

Thanks for your help

Here is the code :

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import DOM (DOM) as DOM
import DOM.HTML (window) as DOM
import DOM.HTML.Document (body) as DOM
import DOM.HTML.Types (htmlElementToElement) as DOM
import DOM.HTML.Window (document) as DOM
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import React (ComponentDidMount, createClass, createFactory, transformState)
import React.DOM as R
import ReactDOM (render)
import Thermite as T

-- MAIN
main ::  Eff (dom :: DOM.DOM ) Unit
main = myMain componentSpec initialState unit

-- | A default implementation of `main` which renders a component to the document body.
myMain :: forall s p a eff . T.Spec eff s p a -> s -> p -> Eff (dom :: DOM.DOM | eff) Unit
myMain spec initialState props = void do
  let reactSpec = (T.createReactSpec spec initialState).spec { componentDidMount = onMount }
  let component = createClass reactSpec
  document  <- DOM.window >>= DOM.document
  container <- DOM.body document
  traverse_ (render (createFactory component props) <<< DOM.htmlElementToElement) container

onMount :: forall props eff . ComponentDidMount props State eff
onMount ctx = transformState ctx (\st -> st { status = "mounted" })

-- STATE
type State = { status :: String }

initialState :: State
initialState = { status: "nothing" }

-- COMPONENT STRUCTURE
componentSpec :: T.Spec _ State _ _
componentSpec = T.simpleSpec performAction render where
    render :: T.Render State _ _
    render dispatch _ s _ = [
      R.div' [ R.text ( s.status) ]
    ]

    performAction :: T.PerformAction _ State _ _
    performAction _ _ _ = void (T.cotransform (\state -> state { status = "something happened"} ))
```

And the error message :

```
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs line 25, column 31 - line 25, column 40

  Could not match type

    state4

  with type

    { status :: String
    }                 


while trying to match type ReactThis props3 state4
  with type ReactThis t5        
              { status :: String
              }                 
while checking that expression reactSpec
  has type { render :: ReactThis t0 t1                                                        
                       -> Eff                                                                 
                            ( props :: ReactProps                                             
                            , refs :: ReactRefs (() :: # Control.Monad.Eff.Effect)            
                            , state :: ReactState                                             
                                         ( read :: Read                                       
                                         )                                                    
                            | t2                                                              
                            )                                                                 
                            ReactElement                                                      
           , displayName :: String                                                            
           , getInitialState :: ReactThis t0 t1                                               
                                -> Eff                                                        
                                     ( props :: ReactProps                                    
                                     , state :: ReactState (() :: # Control.Monad.Eff.Effect) 
                                     , refs :: ReactRefs (() :: # Control.Monad.Eff.Effect)   
                                     | t2                                                     
                                     )                                                        
                                     t1                                                       
           , componentWillMount :: ReactThis t0 t1                                            
                                   -> Eff                                                     
                                        ( props :: ReactProps                                 
                                        , state :: ReactState                                 
                                                     ( read :: Read                           
                                                     , write :: Write                         
                                                     )                                        
                                        , refs :: ReactRefs (() :: # Control.Monad.Eff.Effect)
                                        | t2                                                  
                                        )                                                     
                                        Unit                                                  
           , componentDidMount :: ReactThis t0 t1                                             
                                  -> Eff                                                      
                                       ( props :: ReactProps                                  
                                       , state :: ReactState                                  
                                                    ( read :: Read                            
                                                    , write :: Write                          
                                                    )                                         
                                       , refs :: ReactRefs                                    
                                                   ( read :: Read                             
                                                   )                                          
                                       | t2                                                   
                                       )                                                      
                                       Unit                                                   
           , componentWillReceiveProps :: ReactThis t0 t1                                     
                                          -> t0                                               
                                             -> Eff                                           
                                                  ( props :: ReactProps                       
                                                  , state :: ReactState                       
                                                               ( read :: Read                 
                                                               , write :: Write               
                                                               )                              
                                                  , refs :: ReactRefs                         
                                                              ( read :: Read                  
                                                              )                               
                                                  | t2                                        
                                                  )                                           
                                                  Unit                                        
           , shouldComponentUpdate :: ReactThis t0 t1                                         
                                      -> t0                                                   
                                         -> t1                                                
                                            -> Eff                                            
                                                 ( props :: ReactProps                        
                                                 , state :: ReactState                        
                                                              ( read :: Read                  
                                                              , write :: Write                
                                                              )                               
                                                 , refs :: ReactRefs                          
                                                             ( read :: Read                   
                                                             )                                
                                                 | t2                                         
                                                 )                                            
                                                 Boolean                                      
           , componentWillUpdate :: ReactThis t0 t1                                           
                                    -> t0                                                     
                                       -> t1                                                  
                                          -> Eff                                              
                                               ( props :: ReactProps                          
                                               , state :: ReactState                          
                                                            ( read :: Read                    
                                                            , write :: Write                  
                                                            )                                 
                                               , refs :: ReactRefs                            
                                                           ( read :: Read                     
                                                           )                                  
                                               | t2                                           
                                               )                                              
                                               Unit                                           
           , componentDidUpdate :: ReactThis t0 t1                                            
                                   -> t0                                                      
                                      -> t1                                                   
                                         -> Eff                                               
                                              ( props :: ReactProps                           
                                              , state :: ReactState                           
                                                           ( read :: Read                     
                                                           )                                  
                                              , refs :: ReactRefs                             
                                                          ( read :: Read                      
                                                          )                                   
                                              | t2                                            
                                              )                                               
                                              Unit                                            
           , componentWillUnmount :: ReactThis t0 t1                                          
                                     -> Eff                                                   
                                          ( props :: ReactProps                               
                                          , state :: ReactState                               
                                                       ( read :: Read                         
                                                       )                                      
                                          , refs :: ReactRefs                                 
                                                      ( read :: Read                          
                                                      )                                       
                                          | t2                                                
                                          )                                                   
                                          Unit                                                
           }                                                                                  
in value declaration myMain

where props3 is a rigid type variable
      state4 is a rigid type variable
      t2 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
      t0 is an unknown type
      t5 is an unknown type
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the State type in *myMain* signature

I replaced :

```
myMain :: forall s p a eff . T.Spec eff s p a -> s -> p -> Eff (dom :: DOM.DOM | eff) Unit
```

by :

```
myMain :: forall p a eff . T.Spec eff State p a -> State -> p -> Eff (dom :: DOM.DOM | eff) Unit
```